# How to convert the nvidia-container-toolkit.list in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, nvidia, 22.04, gpu, container

Here is the original `nvidia-container-toolkit.list` from `GitHub`:

https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/nvidia-container-toolkit.list

```
deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/$(ARCH) /
#deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/deb/$(ARCH) /
```

**Here is the document from Nvidia:**

https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/install-guide.html

```
curl -fsSL https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg \
  && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/nvidia-container-toolkit.list | \
    sed 's#deb https://#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://#g' | \
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list
```

I have tried to add the "`signed-by`" manually, and then replace the "`$(ARCH)`" with "`amd64`" or " `amd64`":

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia.gpg] https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/amd64 /

or 

deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia.gpg] https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/ amd64 /
```

But the "`apt-get update`" failed with the following error:

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Here is the `echo $(ARCH)` in Ubuntu:

```
# echo $(ARCH)
ARCH: command not found
```

What's the correct form of "`nvidia-container-toolkit.list`"?

**Update:**

If I did not replace the `$(ARCH)`, the error is still the same. I think the original nvidia document is wrong.

**Update 2:**

The problem may relate to the "$(ARCH)", what's $(ARCH) in the nvidia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their script is broken. I ran the curl script above, and it indeed made a broken sources.list file. So I corrected it, and an `apt update` now works:

```bash
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/amd64 /
#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/deb/amd64 /
```